# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

In one of my files (that I have been told I'm not allowed to modify) I keep getting the following error:

```
In file included from buffer.h:1,
             from buffer.c:4:
semaphore.h:4: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘st_cond_t’
```

When I add the library `st.h` to it, it compiles and runs fine but I've been told I'm not allowed to modify this file so I have to find a way around it and I'm not sure how. Any suggestions? I'll post the relevant code below.

`semaphore.h` : not allowed to edit this file

```c
typedef struct
{
  int value;
  st_cond_t sem_queue;
} semaphore;

void down(semaphore *s);
void up(semaphore *s);
void createSem(semaphore *s, int value);
```

`buffer.h`

```
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "st.h"
#pragma once //necessary to avoid compiler errors

/*this file just defines the structure of a buffer and the methods that will be associated with it. Not too complex */

typedef struct
{
    semaphore *emptyBuffer; //need two semaphores according to slides
    semaphore *fullBuffer;
    int nextIn;
    int nextOut;
    int size;
    char *chars; //literall buffer object
}buffer;

void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, int c); //declaring our functions, similar to an interface in java
int c_remove(buffer *buffer);

buffer *init_buffer(int size);
```

`buffer.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "buffer.h"
#include "st.h"

/* This file fleshes out the methods declared in the header. c_deposit/c_remove are identical in logic to the slides for this assignment, they follow the basic consumer/producer dynamic. init_buffer initializes and provides memory for the elements associated with a buffer struct so that we can access them later */

//prototypes
void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, int c);
int c_remove(buffer *buffer);

buffer *init_buffer(int size);

void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, int c) //code pretty much taken from slides
{
    down(buffer->emptyBuffer); //called down semaphore
    buffer->chars[buffer->nextIn]=c; //put char on char buffer
    buffer->nextIn=(buffer->nextIn+1)%buffer->size; //increment counter
    up(buffer->fullBuffer); //call up semaphore
}
int c_remove(buffer *buffer) //almost identical to deposit
{
    int c;
    down(buffer->fullBuffer);
    c=buffer->chars[buffer->nextOut]; //pull off char
    buffer->nextOut=(buffer->nextOut+1)%buffer->size; //increment
    up(buffer->emptyBuffer);
    return c; //return char
}
buffer *init_buffer(int size) //initializing components of our buffer
{
    //want to malloc so that we don't lose it when we return
    buffer *new_Buffer;
    new_Buffer=malloc((sizeof(buffer)));

    semaphore *sem; //malloc a semaphore and then set the buffer empty/full semaphores equal to it so don't lose it
    sem=malloc(sizeof(semaphore));

    new_Buffer->emptyBuffer=sem; //same as last comment
    createSem(new_Buffer->emptyBuffer, size); //have to create the semaphore

    semaphore *sem2;
    sem2=malloc(sizeof(semaphore));

    new_Buffer->fullBuffer=sem2;
    createSem(new_Buffer->fullBuffer, 0);

    char *array; //malloc for the char buffer
    array=malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    new_Buffer->chars=array;

    new_Buffer->size=size;

    int nextIn=0; //initialize the basic ints
    new_Buffer->nextIn=nextIn;

    int nextOut=0;
    new_Buffer->nextOut=nextOut;

    return new_Buffer;
}
```

`main.c` : just going to include the #include section for reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "st.h"
#include "buffer.h"
```

Comment: show us `semaphore.h` because that where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding `#include "st.h"` in semaphore.h would solve the problem, you could alternatively switch the sequence of includes in buffer.h:

```
 #include "st.h"
 #include "semaphore.h"
```

or, if you're not allowed to do that either, `#include "st.h"` before buffer.h in buffer.c

Comment: wow that worked I didn't know the order mattered! Why is that?

Comment: It's because `#include` is just text replacement and if u use a type like `st_cond_t` somewhere in your code, you have to `typedef` it **before** that line